# Python - Implementing linear algebra formula numpy

Tags: python, numpy, finance

So basically im trying to implement this Markowitz formula:

[image: Formula]

Where e is a vector of 1 dimensions (N,1)
V is a matrix of dimension (N,N)
A is a scalar
µ is a vector of dimension (N,1)

Here is my try:

```
((1-(np.transpose(e).dot(VCinv.dot((e/A)))))/(np.transpose(e).dot(VCinv.dot(e))))*(VCinv.dot(e))+(1/A)*(VCinv.dot(µ))
```

I get a result of the right dimension but nonsensical values, so i'm wondering wether the mistake is in my implementation of the formula or deeper ?

Cheers

V is a variance covariance matrix

Comment: [mcve] please. Saves us the work of making up a test case!  Thisn't something I can work in my head.  I have to code, piece by piece, in a ipython session.

Comment: And please try to write your equation in a clearer way, e.g. for the first fraction split nominator and denominator and assign them to separate variables.

Comment: The equation looks fine to me. I rewrote using Pythons new matrix multiplication operator `@` (which can be used to replace `np.dot` and the short version of `np.transpose` which is `.T`. Then the equation looks like `((1-(e.T @ VCinv @ (e/A))) / (e.T @ VCinv @ e)) * (VCinv @ e) + (1/A)*(VCinv @ mu)` which is far easier to verify.